# Unique visitors + Page Path + Countryon Google analytics API?

Tags: php, google-analytics, analytics

Is there a way to know, for example for the 15th of June, how many visitors (unique) went on how many pages, and from what country where they from ?
Like a way to get an array with, for example for the page '/index.php' :
'USA' => 5628,
'Canada' => 2000,
etc...

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

by parsing your access logs, you can take the IP address and use the [geoip](http://us.php.net/geoip) functions

Comment: I don't have access to the log files (shared hosting).
Thanks.

(besides it's on IIS)

Comment: in that case use google-analytics.  drop the pixel on each of your pages and google will take care of the rest

Comment: most of googles API's are just atom feeds.  Zend framework has some great functions to get data from google you can check the Zend_Gdata class of funcitons from the framework.  Best resource would be google itself:
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/